How does one install an ARM build of Python on macos?
Background: I develop and run physics simulations in python using JAX, which supports GPUs, including on apple M-series machines (see jax-metal).
Following the instructions there results in an error when verifying the installation:
RuntimeError: This version of jaxlib was built using AVX instructions, 
which your CPU and/or operating system do not support. This error is 
frequently encountered on macOS when running an x86 Python installation 
on ARM hardware. In this case, try installing an ARM build of Python. 
Otherwise, you may be able work around this issue by building jaxlib from source.

Following the suggestions at this stackoverflow question it appears that my installation of python is indeed x86_64.
Question:
How can I get an ARM build of python?
Further details: I am running an M3 mac, with Sonoma 14.6.1. My main python is python12.
Attempts:

Installing with the universal installer from python.org
Installing with miniforge, as described here
Installing with pyenv through homebrew

All of these resulted in x86_64 builds of python.

How do you do you test the architecture? Did you activate one env? (just to be sure you are not using a different python installation? conda (so miniforge) should support environment with the two architecture (in parallel, but in different virtual environments)

To start with I was creating envs to test, but eventually I just started testing the base installation to see if it worked (just using the full path to the python executable - in some cases, I downloaded different python versions to check, and the python version always matched what I was expecting). If there's a particular command that will use an arm build, I'd love to know what that is.

Note: installing a new python, do not remove the old one, and nobody can be sure on what python is being used. I think that is your main problem: you are always testing the same python installation. So you should be sure you are running the binary you want (so I asked how did you test the architecture).

Interesting. If I install a new python with a version that's not already on my system (as I did for each of the approaches I tried), I'd think that if I can verify my python version that should be sufficient to know which python is being used (if for some reason literally using the entire path to the executable is not sufficient). Is there anything you suggest I try? I suppose I could create envs, but wouldn't the doubt about python versions apply to that too?

which python in command line tell you where your shell find the first python binary. Each virtual environment can have a different python version (we use conda so we can have different python version in parallel, e.g. to test upgrades).. But when you activate a virtual nevironment, the activation script should put the expected version as first python in your shell (check with which command.

Thanks for all the help. I've solved the issue - I did have ARM python already on my machine, but somehow homebrew was interfering. I'm still not entirely sure what originally caused the issue, but properly sorting out all the python versions, cleaning up my PATH, etc. has solved it.
